# How to return unique records in (multiple) associations in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

First and foremost, thanks to everyone taking time to read through this post. Many, many thanks in advance.

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve all the ***unique*** locations names a provider might have.

My first idea was to write a method in the Provider model that would iterate through all courses then occurrence and return a list of unique locations.

I've looked at the [.uniq](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-uniq) method in the Rails api but without any luck.

Here's what my different models/associations looks like:

models/provider.rb

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :teachers
end
```

models/course.rb

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :occurrences, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :provider
end
```

models/occurrence.rb

```
class Occurrence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :location
end
```

models/location.rb

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :occurrences
end
```

What's the best way of achieving this?

After reading the coments I'Ve tried this:

I've created a unique_locations method in the Provider model it has the following code (based on your answer)

```
def unique_locations
  Location.joins(occurrences: :course).where(courses: { provider_id: self.id }).uniq.pluck('locations.name')
end`
```

and using it in my view:

```
<% @provider.unique_locations.each do |l| %>
  <%= l %><br>
<% end %>`
```

But I'm still getting non-unique results. Any ideas?

Comment: Why `.uniq` won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `Location.uniq.pluck(:name)` which will return an array of unique location names.  Going from the provider, you have to use `:joins` (given a `@provider`)

```
Location.joins(occurences: :course).where(courses: { provider_id: @provider.id }).uniq.pluck('locations.name')
```

Comment: Added more info to original post @jvnill

Comment: Ah it did the trick alright! Is it following "Best Practices" to write this type of method or I would have been better off writing a scope?

Comment: You can add 2 more `has_many` associations to provider. `has_many :occurences, through: :courses` and `has_many :locations, through: :occurences` then just call `provider.locations.uniq.pluck(:name)`